# For which integers $r,a,b$ and $c$ is $\frac{r^a-r^b}{r^c-1}$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

From geometric progression formula, we know that $$\frac{r^n-1}{r-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} r^i.$$ Hence the left hand side is always an integer, for all integers $r \neq 1$ and all $n\geq 1$.

> **Question.** For which integers $r,a,b$ and $c$ is $$\frac{r^a-r^b}{r^c-1}$$ an integer?

I left off the obvious $r^d$ generalization because we can just divide top and bottom by $r^{\mathrm{min}(c,d)}$ to reduce the problem to the above form.

Answer (score 1):

You can rephrase this problem as "when is $r^a\equiv r^b\pmod{r^c-1}$?".

When $c$ is a positive integer
and $r\ge2$, the sequence $(r^a)$ is periodic modulo $r^c-1$
with exact period $c$.

Answer (score 1):

For non-negative integers $m,n$, there is a general rule, $$\gcd(r^m-1,r^n-1)=r^{\gcd(m,n)}-1.$$

Assuming $a\geq b$ and $a,b,c$ non-negative integers we then have:

$$\gcd(r^a-r^b,r^c-1)=r^{\gcd(a-b,c)}-1$$

So for $r^c-1$ to be a divisor of $r^a-r^b$, you must have $c$ a divisor of $a-b$.

(The other case, $b\geq a$, also reduces to $c$ being a divisor of $a-b$.

Cases where $a,b,c$ can be negative can be gotten with care. If $c>0$ you have either that $a=b$ or $a,b\geq 0$.

If $c<0$ then this is the same as $\frac{r^{a-c}-r^{b-c}}{1-r^{-c}}$ is an integer, which is only possible if $a=b$ or if $a-c,b-c\geq 0$ and $c\mid a-b.$